# Change slideshow image selection based on screen size - Shopify

Tags: css, shopify

I am trying to display two different slideshows based on screen size on my shopify store. I have created a section called section-mobile-slideshow and used the following code to display this section when a mobile screen size is detected:

```
     #shopify-section-mobile-slideshow {
      display: none !important;
    }
  @media (max-width: 450px){ 
    #shopify-section-slideshow {
      display: none !important;
    }
    #shopify-section-mobile-slideshow {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
```

This works great on a mobile phone but on my laptop I see both slideshows. How can I then hide the mobile slideshow when the screen size is above a certain amount of pixels?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite the same. Just as you removed the PC version of the slide show in mobile you can use `@media only screen and (min-width: 451px)` and then set the Mobile slideshow ID to `display: none;`.

E.g.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 451px)
{
    #shopify-section-mobile-slideshow
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the code you provided at the end of my theme.scss.liquid
 file and both slideshows are still visible. Have I put the code in the wrong place?